# how to create plotly line chart in shinyapp with multiple level variable

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, r-plotly

Hi im trying to plot  simple chart using plotly in the Shiny app. It is a line chart with Frequency variable on the X-Axis and a Metric on y-axis. i'm expecting two lines in the charts as i'm calling in a variable that has two levels in the UI. i'm getting the chart when i have one input from the groupcheckbox, but the goes blank when i select two options. i dont know what i'm doing wrong here, I'm not getting any error notifications.thanks for your inputs in advance

pasting the code with data here.

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(readxl)

prod<-c("BrandB", "BrandA", "BrandB", "BrandA", "BrandB", "BrandA","BrandB","BrandA","BrandB","BrandA","BrandB","BrandA","BrandB","BrandA","BrandB","BrandA")
Freq<-c("W7","W7","W8","W8","W9","W9","W10","W10","W10","W10","W7","W7","W8","W8","W9","W9")
Metric1<-c(0.515,0.444,0.518,0.446,0.529,0.405,0.497,0.376,0.505,0.494,0.515,0.444,0.518,0.446,0.529,0.405)
Cut<-c("RBs","RBs","RBs","RBs","RBs","RBs","Total","Total","RBs","RBs","Total","Total","Total","Total","Total","Total")

DF<-data.frame(prod,Freq,Metric1,Cut)

str(DF)

DF$Brand<-as.factor(DF$prod)
DF$Wave<-factor(DF$Freq,levels=c("W7","W8","W9","W10"))

#View(DF)

ui <- fluidPage(
    
    # useShinydashboard(),
    
    titlePanel("Dassy"),
    
    fluidRow(
        
        column(3,
               checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "Prod", 
                                  label = "Choose Fill For the Chart",
                                  choices = c("BrandA" = "BrandA","BrandB" = "BrandB"),
                                  selected = "BrandA"
               )),
        column(3,
               selectInput(inputId = "Cut", 
                           label = "Choose Fill For the Chart",
                           choices = c("Total" = "Total","RBs" = "RBs"),
                           selected = "Total")
        ),actionButton("go_button", "GO !")
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
        plotlyOutput("distPlot"))
)


server <- function(input, output) {
    
    observeEvent(input$go_button,{
        output$distPlot <- renderPlotly({
            
            DF1 <- reactive({
                
                DF%>%filter(Cut == input$Cut & prod == input$Prod)
            }
            )
           
            p1<-plot_ly(DF1(),x=~Freq, y=~Metric1, color =  ~prod, width=1200, height=300)%>% add_lines(line = list(shape = "spline")) 
            p1<-p1%>%layout(yaxis=list(tickformat ="%"))
            
        })
        #observe Event
    })
    
}
#??plot_ly()

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[With single option selected line graph generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cbUB.png)

[With two option selected blank chart gets generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfRFx.png)

Comment: Thanks Ben,  i tried it, but output is the same.but this time i got  a warning message shown below  Warning in RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(N, "Set2") :
  minimal value for n is 3, returning requested palette with 3 different levels

Comment: Sorry, I meant `filter(Cut == input$Cut & prod %in% input$Prod)`

Comment: This works perfect now! thank you Ben.